# Inherit WPF-UserControl from generic base class

Tags: wpf, generics, inheritance

I've got the error "The Tag "EntityView.MainContent" does not exist in the "clr-namespace:Lvt.Views"."

I want to inherit from a generic base class like the following.

C#-Code:

```
public class EntityView<T> : UserControl where T :IEntityViewModel
{
   // Property with set and get a Dependency Property
   public object MainContent {get {...} set{...}
}
```

XAML-Code:

```
<local:EntityView x:TypeArguments="viewModels:EntityViewModel" x:Class="Lvt.Views.SpecialEntityView"
   <local:EntityView.MainContent>
      <Grid></Grid>
   </local:EntityView.MainContent>
</local:EntityView>
```

XAML-CodeBehind:

```
public partial class SpecialEntityView : EntityView<EntityViewModel>
{
   public SpecialEntityView() { InitializeComponent(); }
}
```

Does anyone know why this error message is displayed?
Thanks, Alex